# What is the optimal way to perform a delayed sampling with Rx?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I'm working on a Xamarin app where I have extended the [Connectivity](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/ConnectivityPlugin) plugin to use Rx rather than events.

My goal was to introduce a slight delay when connectivity is re-established to allow the network adapter time to connect to the internet (workaround for UWP). If any values appear within this delay, only the last one needs to be kept since only the current connection state matters.

This works fine, but it feels a bit hacky:

```
internal static class ConnectivityExtensions
{
    public static IObservable<bool> ToObservable(this IConnectivity @this)
    {
        var connectivity = Observable
            .FromEventPattern<ConnectivityChangedEventHandler, ConnectivityChangedEventArgs>(
                handler => @this.ConnectivityChanged += handler,
                handler => @this.ConnectivityChanged -= handler)
            .Select(args => args.EventArgs.IsConnected);

        var sampling = connectivity
            .Timestamp()
            .Select(ts => new
            {
                ts.Value,
                ts.Timestamp,
                // If reconnection, delay subscriber notification for 250ms
                DelayUntil = ts.Value ? (DateTimeOffset?)ts.Timestamp.Add(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250)) : null
            })
            .Scan((acc, current) => new
            {
                current.Value,
                current.Timestamp,
                // If current notification is during reconnection notification delay period, delay the current notification too
                DelayUntil = current.Timestamp < acc.DelayUntil ? acc.DelayUntil : current.DelayUntil
            })
            // Perform reconnection delay
            .Delay(x => x.DelayUntil.HasValue
                ? Observable.Return(x.DelayUntil.Value).Delay(x.DelayUntil.Value)
                : Observable.Empty<DateTimeOffset>())
            // All delayed notifications are delayed until the same time, so we only need one notification to trigger sampling after delay
            .DistinctUntilChanged()
            .Select(_ => Unit.Default);

        return connectivity
            .Sample(sampling)
            .StartWith(@this.IsConnected)
            .DistinctUntilChanged()
            .Replay(1)
            .RefCount();
    }
}
```

### Example Output:

With this example, you can hopefully see the benefit of what I'm doing. The delay prevents subscribers from processing data when "connectivity" changes, but internet connection has not been established (UWP). Additionally, this also protects subscribers from any quick "on/off" notifications.

```
                                                                                     // StartsWith: True
ConnectivityChanged(null, new ConnectivityChangedEventArgs { IsConnected = true });  // Delay 250ms
Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250));                                        // Sample: True, Ignored due to DistinctUntilChanged
ConnectivityChanged(null, new ConnectivityChangedEventArgs { IsConnected = false }); // Sample: False
Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250));
ConnectivityChanged(null, new ConnectivityChangedEventArgs { IsConnected = true });  // Delay 250ms, Discarded due to Sample
ConnectivityChanged(null, new ConnectivityChangedEventArgs { IsConnected = false }); // Delayed by previous, Discarded due to Sample
ConnectivityChanged(null, new ConnectivityChangedEventArgs { IsConnected = true });  // Delayed by previous, Discarded due to Sample
ConnectivityChanged(null, new ConnectivityChangedEventArgs { IsConnected = false }); // Delayed by previous
Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250));                                        // Sample: False, Ignored due to DistinctUntilChanged
ConnectivityChanged(null, new ConnectivityChangedEventArgs { IsConnected = true });  // Delay 250ms, Discarded due to Sample
ConnectivityChanged(null, new ConnectivityChangedEventArgs { IsConnected = false }); // Delayed by previous
Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250));                                        // Sample: False, Ignored due to DistinctUntilChanged

// Final Output:
// True
// False
```

---

**Is there a more optimal way to achieve this type of delayed sampling?**

Comment: Have to tested with Rx to be sure that is really works?  Usually windows applications need Rx events to keep up with data.  Windows can have large pauses during process swapping.  Do you need continuous data monitoring?  Delay sampling will skip some data and most application will not work if data is missed.

Comment: @jdweng I'm not sure what you're talking about. The Rx I'm referring to is [Reactive Extensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh242985(v=vs.103).aspx) (see question tags), which is a concept that can be applied across different operating systems. I'm using this connectivity monitoring to toggle UI visibility and data sync on connection state changes. The data skipped here is not important since, as I mentioned, only the current connection state matters.

Comment: The logic of what you're trying to achieve with the `Select/Scan/Delay` combination is hard to read through. Can you provide a description?

Comment: @Shlomo Added some comments to the code that hopefully help describe the intent.

Comment: @TaylorBuchanan - Can you please be a bit more explicit about what you need? I don't understand the current explanation or the sample code.

Comment: @Enigmativity "true" values start a 250ms delay period, unless they are produced within an existing delay period. Only the last value produced in the delay period should be used. After the 250ms, all subsequent values should be produced on time. This is what the current code is doing. I realize it's fairly hard to understand, which is the whole point for this question.

Comment: @TaylorBuchanan - And after the 250ms triggered by a `true` then "all subsequent values" must be `false`? Can there be more than one `false` in a sequence? Your sample code doesn't show that. So it's still a little unclear to me.

Comment: @Enigmativity I don't know for sure since I don't know the networking details for each Xamarin platform, but I don't think it would make sense for the connection to go from "false" to "false". It doesn't really matter anyway, the code I provided works either way. I'm just looking for a cleaner alternative. Being newer to Rx, I assumed there would be one.

Comment: @TaylorBuchanan - Probably there is, but know the semantics of the data can make a difference. If it's always `true` then `false` alternating it might make a big difference to having a clean query. It probably does matter to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon revisiting this almost a year later, I discovered an undocumented overload for `Throttle` which allows for great simplification of what I was trying to do. I also created my own reactive `IConnectivity` abstraction to reduce dependency on the specific library:

```
internal sealed class ReactiveCrossConnectivity : IConnectivity
{
    public IObservable<bool> IsConnected { get; }

    public ReactiveCrossConnectivity(
        Plugin.Connectivity.Abstractions.IConnectivity connectivity, 
        ISchedulerProvider scheduler)
    {
        IsConnected = Observable
            .FromEventPattern<ConnectivityChangedEventHandler, ConnectivityChangedEventArgs>(
                handler => connectivity.ConnectivityChanged += handler,
                handler => connectivity.ConnectivityChanged -= handler,
                scheduler.Defaults.ConstantTimeOperations)
            .Select(args => args.EventArgs.IsConnected)
            .Throttle(isConnected => isConnected
                ? Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250),
                      scheduler.Defaults.TimeBasedOperations)
                : Observable.Return<long>(0))
            .StartWith(scheduler.Defaults.ConstantTimeOperations, connectivity.IsConnected)
            .DistinctUntilChanged()
            .Replay(1, scheduler.Defaults.Iteration)
            .RefCount();
    }
}
```

Here's the NUnit/NSubstitute test that confirms the behavior:

```
public sealed class ReactiveCrossConnectivityTest : ReactiveTest
{
    [Test]
    public void IsConnected_ThrottlesOnConnect()
    {
        var connectivity = Substitute.For<Plugin.Connectivity.Abstractions.IConnectivity>();
        connectivity.IsConnected.Returns(true);
        var testScheduler = new TestScheduler();
        var sut = new ReactiveCrossConnectivity(
            connectivity, new SingleSchedulerProvider(testScheduler));
        var isConnectedObserver = testScheduler.CreateObserver<bool>();

        sut.IsConnected.Subscribe(isConnectedObserver);

        void Change(bool isConnected) => connectivity.ConnectivityChanged +=
            Raise.Event<ConnectivityChangedEventHandler>(connectivity,
                new ConnectivityChangedEventArgs { IsConnected = isConnected });

        testScheduler.Schedule(TimeSpan.FromTicks(3), () => Change(true));
        testScheduler.Schedule(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(251), () => Change(false));
        testScheduler.Schedule(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(501), () => Change(true));
        testScheduler.Schedule(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(751), () => Change(true));
        testScheduler.Schedule(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(752), () => Change(false));
        testScheduler.Schedule(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(753), () => Change(true));
        testScheduler.Schedule(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(754), () => Change(false));
        testScheduler.Schedule(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1001), () => Change(true));
        testScheduler.Schedule(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1002), () => Change(false));

        testScheduler.Start();

        isConnectedObserver.Messages.AssertEqual(
            OnNext(2, true),
            OnNext(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(251).Ticks + 1, false));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a marble diagram of how things will work out, if I understand correctly:

```
T (millis)           : 0----250--500--1000-1250-1500-1750-2000
Connectivity         : ---F-------T---F----T-------F--T-------
ScanValueDelayUntil  : ---null----800-null-1500----null2100---
Sampling             : -------------x-----------x-----------x-
ResultSampled        : T------------T-----------T-----------T-
ResultSampledDistinct: T--------------------------------------
```

That doesn't seem very meaningful. Can you either describe what you want the result to represent, or correct where I'm wrong?

Comment: The diagram appears to be incorrect. Passing IObservable (sampling) to the Sample method emits the last value since the time of each value in the sampling, not at a regular interval like in the diagram. It's hard to tell on my phone the exact timing in the diagram, but I think based on your values the ResultSampled would be: T F F T F T. StartsWith isn't part of the sample, so there isn't a delay at the start. T at 500 would cause 250ms delay, but value would be ignored since F at 750 happened within the delay. I'll try to post my own example when back at a computer.